# codeigniter regex_match matching for 'two length values'

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-match

I have this regex_match like -

```
    regex_match[/^[0-9]{13}$/ ]
```

It validates all 13-digit integers. But I can't seem to find a way for allowing only 10-digit and 13-digit integers to pass as input. I tried all kinds of code like

```
    regex_match[/^[0-9]{13|10}$/ ] ,

    regex_match[/^[0-9]{13}{10}$/ ]
```

and even

```
    regex_match[/^[0-9]{13}$/ ] | regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/ ]
```

but none of them is working. 
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this..This is tested..

```
$number="12541254192";
    if( preg_match('/^([0-9]{13}|[0-9]{10})$/', number)==1){
        echo "Matching";
    }else{
        echo "Not Matching";
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked easily. Yet one question remains unanswered - "why does escaping the brackets in 
        regex_match[/^([0-9]{13}|[0-9]{10})$/] didn't work at all?"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
regex_match[/^([0-9]{13}|[0-9]{10})$/]
```

You might need to escape the brackets.